# Where to ask: Is OpenGL 4.5 supported on enough hardware that it can used without worrying about too many people being unable to use my application?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have the following question:

> Is OpenGL 4.5 supported on enough hardware that it can be safely used without worrying about too many people being unable to use my application?

Should I post it on Stack Overflow or Software Recommendation, or some other site? After all, the question of something being supported *enough* is a bit opinion-based. By "enough" I mean something like about 95% (the percentage of PCs running Windows according to Steam's statistics).

Comment: It might be good to add clarification regarding what you consider to be "enough hardware" in this case.

Comment: You basically ask: *What is the minimum hardware spec OpenGL 4.5 will run and how many users worldwide will have that hardware*. If those numbers are not known, it is too broad to be answered anywhere. I would maybe expect that on Super User you'll find a crowd that can answer the minimal spec part but I wouldn't have high hopes that get that complete question answered there.

Comment: Ok, I'll start of with Super User than. Thanks.

Comment: There have been similarly general questions on [gamedev.se]. But maybe [computergraphics.se] would work, too. I am, however, not entirely sure about that (hence not answering), so take that as a very cautious suggestion.